# How to Build a Table neglecting all computations out of diagonal?

Tags: matrix

I would like to build a vector with the values obtained from computation of the diagonal terms of the following Table:

```
 Table[Table[l + j, {l, 0, 10, 1}], {j, 0, 0.1, 0.01}] // MatrixForm
```

My real Table is much more complicated and time consuming, therefore I am looking for a fast way to avoid all computations of terms out of diagonal. Is there any function or way?

I would like to underline that my real Table has the following shape, which is forcing me to find a smart way to compute the diagonal terms:

```
vectorj=Table[j,{j, 0, 0.1, 0.01}]
f[x_]=Table[x^2*j,{j,vectorj}]   
Table[j*f[x][[j]],{j,1,Length[vectorj]}] // MatrixForm
```

The problem is that I need in the last table j to be an integer to get the [[j]] term of f[x], but the multypling factor j should be actually the value in the j position, say in position 2, that should be 0.01. I want to avoid building too many tables so I thought there might be a way to avoid useless computations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To talk about a diagonal of the matrix it must be square. So in general make each of your two vectors (which are equal length due to squareness):

```
ivector=Table[i,{i,0,10,1}];
jvector=Table[j,{j,0,0.1,0.001}];
```

Then apply your matrix function `f[i,j]` to these two vectors as `f[t,t]` along the diagonal:

```
answer=Table[ivector[[t]]+jvector[[t]],{t,1,Length[ivector]}]
```

Comment: a couple of things: first, isn't there syntax error in the definition of ivector and jvector? secondly, i don't get anything after running your code

Comment: Yes there was a typo in my two vectors. This is now fixed. This error was what was causing there to be no output.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd rewrite your code above

```
Table[Table[l + j, {l, 0, 10, 1}], {j, 0, 0.1, 0.01}] // MatrixForm
```

into

```
Table[l + j/100, {j, 0, 10}, {l, 0, 10}] // MatrixForm
```

Now the indices are comparable, and you can just write the following to get the diagonal elements:

```
Table[j + j/100, {j, 0, 10}]
```

In general, if you are making `j` do double duty as both an argument to a function and an index to a table, better to treat it fundamentally as an integer index and compute the argument.

Comment: ok this is fine if we can make the indices comparable. In this case we were lucky because of that 1/100 factor. And in a general case where this is not possible?

Comment: I think it will always be possible to rewrite into an integer index form, since it is just a linear transformation from the original sequence to the sequence `{0,1,2,...}`. Can you think of a counter-example?

Comment: Values that I want the function to assume: 0, 0.1, 0.6, 100, 1023.5;
Indices of the vector: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
What do you think of such a case?